# Spring Integration causes multiple beans error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I'm using Spring Boot  and trying use Spring integration (because I want to use its SFTP client). But I got the following error:

```
Description:
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.service.ServiceOne required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - applicationTaskExecutor: defined by method 'applicationTaskExecutor' in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/task/TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration.class]
    - taskScheduler: defined in null


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

I'm sure that the error happens after adding dependencies for spring-integration. I've tried to use `@Qualifier("applicationTaskExecutor")` and creating a bean with `@Primary` annotation but still unable to run the application. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As error stated there are two `TaskExecutor` beans in the application context.
One is auto-configured by the `TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration` and another by Spring Integration for its pollers features which is essentially a `TaskScheduler`.

What the error description suggest is to use a `@Qualifier("applicationTaskExecutor")` on the `ServiceOne` 's Parameter 0 of constructor. You don't need to have `@Primary` bean because the story is about beans created outside of your code.